# performance difference in two almost same loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, performance, optimization

I got two almost same loop, but with remarkable difference in performance, both tested with MSVC2010, on system ~2.4 GHZ and 8GB RAM

Below loop take around 2500 ms to execute

```
for (double count = 0; count < ((2.9*4/555+3/9)*109070123123.8); count++)
;
```

And this loop execute in less then 1 ms

```
for (double count = ((2.9*4/555+3/9)*109070123123.8); count >0; --count)
;
```

What making such huge difference here? One got post increment and other using pre-increment can it result in such huge difference?

Comment: If you enable optimization, booth loops should collapse to NOTHING, and thus take 0 time. Don't try to measure performance with optimization turned off!

Comment: -1 there is no point in talking about performance when not using at least the most trivial optimisations.

Comment: 1ms is not a change in performance. You have to mention what you achive with it i.e. MFLOPS (Standard array) or MLUPS (Grid Calculation).
Lets consider how the for loop works. `Step1: Assign Value to Variable.` `Step2: Check If condition is true and Execute Block of Code` `Step3: Increment` `Step4: Repeat Step2 and Step3`. In the first loop you need to calculate the value of expression for every iteration and in second loop you do the calculation only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're compiling without optimizations, so the comparison is futile. (If you did have optimizations on, that code would just be cut out completely).

Without optimization, the computation is likely executed at each iteration in the first loop, whereas the second loop only does the computation once, when it first initializes `count`.

Try changing the first loop to

```
auto max = ((2.9*4/555+3/9)*109070123123.8);
for (double count = 0; count < max; count++)
;
```

and then stop profiling debug builds.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop `count < ((2.9*4/555+3/9)*109070123123.8)` is computed every time round the loop where as in the second `count = ((2.9*4/555+3/9)*109070123123.8)` is calculated once and decremented each time round the loop.